# breaking a single json file into two models and one collection with backbone and $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js

I have a single JSON file called products and need to split this.

The structure of this file is like this

I am envisaging that I need to have one collection (as I dont want to read in the json file twice) and two models (productType and product)

```
productTypeList
   0
     id
     name
     productList
       0
         id
         name
       1
         id
         name
       2
         id
         name
       3
         id
         name
   1
     id
     name
     productList
   2
     id 
     name
     productList
```

I was thinking of using a getJson command to do this. I did play with the idea of using backbone url within the collection but this seems more suited to when data is being taken from a restful API and not a static json file, would these assumptions be correct?

Anyway if I do go down the route of having two models and one collection how would this work seeing as you define a method in a collection?

I would assume to have models like this

```
var ProductType=Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        id:"",
        name:'',
        longName:''

    }
});

return ProductType

var Product=Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults:{
        id:"",
        name:'',
        ordering:'',
        introSmall:'',
        introNormal:'',
        sellingPoints:'',
        interestRate:'',
        interestRateLabel:''
        productTypeID:''

    }
});

return Product;
```

and then I am not sure how the collection will work... I have added some comments/questions?

```
var Products=Backbone.Collection.extend({

      // Do i call both models here??
      model:ProductType,
      model:Product,

      fetch:function(){
        var self=this;
        var tmpItem;
        var tmpProduct

           var jqxhr = $.getJSON("data/product.json")
          .success(function(data, status, xhr) { 

            $.each(data.productTypeList, function(i,item){

              tmpItem=new ProductType({


        id:item.id,
            name:item.name,
            longName:item.longName,
            ordering:item.ordering
                });

                     $.each(data.productTypeList[i], function(a,itemProduct){

                     tmpProduct = new Product ({
                     id:itemProduct.id,
             name:itemProduct.name,
             ordering:itemProduct.ordering,
             introSmall:itemProduct.introSmall,
                         productTypeID:i
                     });

                    self.add(tmpProduct);

                     });


              self.add(tmpItem);

            });
            //dispatch customized event
            self.trigger("fetchCompleted:Products");

          })
          .error(function() { alert("error"); })
          .complete(function() {
                console.log("fetch complete + " + this);
          });





      }
```

any help is really appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it might make sense to split the problem into two steps:

1. Fetch the data file and process the contents into "model-ready" form
2. Instantiate your models/collections based the parsed data.

The general idea is to keep non-Backbone-type things (ie, parsing an awkward data format) away from your models and collections until it's in a format that they'll understand. This keeps them nice and trim, and will isolate the tricky part of the code off in its own space.

So, for the first step, you ought to be able to do something on these lines:

```
var parseResponse = function (data) {

  var result = { types: [], models: [] };

  var type, 
      types = data.productTypeList,
      product,
      i = types.length;

  while (type = types[--i]) {
    result.types.push({ 
       id: type.id,
       name: type.name
       // etc.
    });
    while (product = type.productList.pop()) {
      product.productTypeId = type.id;
      result.models.push(product);
    }
  }
};

$.getJSON('...', parseResponse);
```

By the end of the `parseResponse` method (you'll need to finish implementing it), the `result` variable now contains a list of product types. The final touch is to create the `productType` and `product` collections. Assuming you've got `ProductCollection` and `ProductTypeCollection` collections with the appropriate models set, you can "Backbone-ify" the data you parsed into `result` along these lines:

```
var products = new ProductCollection(result.models)
var productTypes = new ProductTypeCollection(result.modelTypes);
```

Comment: thanks - will give it a go .. the logic sounds a lot better that what I was thinking. will let you know how I go then accept the answer - but appreciate your time

Comment: I still have a couple of queries - would you mind if i added them to a new tickets as this comments area is to small?

Answer (score 0):

deciced to keep it here.. will remove/edit later and keep answer so people see resolution

so my project is using jqm, jquery, backbone and require

I have setup jqm so that it doesnt do any routing and have let backbone deal with that

on my router page i have

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
        '':    'showHome',         //home view
        'home': 'showHome',        //home view as well
        'products/productList' : 'showProducts',

        '*actions': 'defaultAction' 
    },

initialize:function () {
    // Handle back button throughout the application
    $('.back').live('click', function(event) {
        window.history.back();
        return false;
    });
    this.firstPage = true;
},


parseResponse : function(data) {

 result = { prodTypes: [], products: [] };
       var type;
   var types = data.data.productTypeList;
   var product;
   var i = types.length;


            while (type = types[--i]) {
            result.prodTypes.push({ 
               id: type.id,
               name: type.name,
               longName: type.longName

            });
            while (product = type.productList.pop()) {
              product.productTypeId = type.id,
              result.products.push(product);
            }
          }


    },


    defaultAction: function(actions){
        this.showHome();
    },

    showHome:function(actions){
        // will render home view and navigate to homeView
        var homeView=new HomeView();
        homeView.render(); 

        this.changePage(homeView, 'fade');
    },



    showProducts:function(){

        $.getJSON('data/product.json', this.parseResponse).success(function(data, status, xhr) { 


     var productList=new Products(result.prodTypes);
     var productListView=new ProductListView({collection:productList});

     productListView.bind('renderCompleted:Products',this.changePage,this);

     productListView.update();

       });   


    },

    changePage:function (view, transition) {
        //add the attribute 'data-role="page" ' for each view's div

        console.log("pagechanged");
        if (transition != "slidefade") {
         transition = "pop";                
        }

        view.$el.attr('data-role', 'page');   
        $('.ui-page').attr('data-role', 'page');

        //append to dom
        $('body').append(view.$el);  


        if(!this.init){   
            $.mobile.changePage($(view.el), {changeHash:false, transition: transition});


        }else{   
            this.init = false;
        }            
    }       

});

$(document).ready(function () {
console.log('App Loaded');
app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
});

return AppRouter;
```

my collection page

```
        var Products=Backbone.Collection.extend({

      // Book is the model of the collection
      model:ProductType,


      //fetch data from books.json using Ajax 
      //and then dispatch customized event "fetchCompleted:Books"
      fetch:function(){
        var self=this;
        var tmpItem;
        var tmpProduct;
        //fetch the data using ajax

        $.each(result.prodTypes, function(i,prodType){

            tmpItem=new ProductType({id:prodType.id,    name:prodType.name, longName:prodType.longName});

            self.add(tmpItem);
        });

        self.trigger("fetchCompleted:Products");  
      }
});

return Products;
```

my view page

```
  var ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({

template: _.template(productViewTemplate),

update:function(){
  //set callback of the event "fetchCompleted:Products" 
  this.collection.bind('fetchCompleted:Products',this.render,this);
  this.collection.fetch();
  console.log(this.collection);
},

render: function(){
  this.$el.empty();
  //compile template using the data fetched by collection
  this.$el.append(this.template({data:this.collection.toJSON()}));
  this.trigger("renderCompleted:Products",this);

  return this;
}
});

return ProductListView;
```

the problem is two things..

firstly and mainly when i click to go to the second page it doesnt go there... but it doesnt throw an error.

the data is going through to the page but nothing is happening?

the console.log within the update function of the view does execute so I am baffled.

the second and a minor one - i want to include

```
$.getJSON('data/product.json', this.parseResponse).success(function(data, status, xhr) {
```

on the initalize function on the router but if I do and call result.prodTypes or this.result.prodTypes it says its undefined as its part of another function and I can work out how to call it - at the moment its on the show products action but this will cause problems as i will need to use products: [] in diff places and dont want to call the json twice

thanks